# Firefox and Safari setting incorrect header for ContentType when using FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

We have a file upload code section where we use Form data to send to the file to the backend service.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('classFile', values.file || new Blob(), values.file ? values.file.name : '');
```

We make a http post request to the backend to send this data. We are noticing that the Content Type is set correctly to multipart/formdata on chrome
[Chrome request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzjVh.png)
whereas Firefox/Safari sets them to application/json.
[Firefox request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krssQ.png)
We do not pass any explicit headers on the post request. Any help on how to fix it is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question, what can we help you with?

Comment: Can you try to add 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in your request header by manually.

Comment: @dogukyilmaz Found an article on form data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects stating `When using FormData to submit POST requests using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch_API with the multipart/form-data Content-Type (e.g. when uploading Files and Blobs to the server), do not explicitly set the Content-Type header on the request. Doing so will prevent the browser from being able to set the Content-Type header with the boundary expression it will use to delimit form fields in the request body.`

Comment: @shanvj are you making XMLHttpRequest? The link you send is related to that i guess.
Please check out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: @dogukyilmaz we use http post. Tried adding the 'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata' to the header but I see Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found on firefox. Tried adding the boundary parameter similar to how chrome uses "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFjRqNceIRD4QTnIj" did not work on firefox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting explicit Content-Type: multipart/formdata header ?

Comment: Tried adding the 'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata' to the header but I see Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found on firefox. Tried adding the boundary parameter similar to how chrome uses "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFjRqNceIRD4QTnIj" did not work on firefox

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue by upgrading the version of axios package that was used for the http calls to the latest version. We can now see the content type and boundary automatically set by the browser in both firefox/safari correctly when doing a http post.